# Rendering Ansible template into the fact variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Is there a way to render Ansible template into the fact? I tried to find a solution but it looks like temp file is the the only way.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think you might be just looking for the [`template` lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_lookup.html):

```
- set_fact:
    rendered_template: "{{ lookup('template', './template.j2') }}"
```

---

Usage example:

- `template.j2`

  ```
    Hello {{ value_for_template }}
  ```
- `playbook.yml`

  ```
    ---
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: no
      connection: local
      vars:
        value_for_template: world
      tasks:
        - debug:
            var: rendered_template
          vars:
            rendered_template: "{{ lookup('template', './template.j2') }}"
  ```
- The result:

  ```
    TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "rendered_template": "Hello world\n"
    }
  ```

Comment: This solution is not suitable for every use case, as set_facts doesn't change the variable value. So if another task depends on on a change, it will not run.

Comment: This also assumes the template to be rendered is a template _file_. What if the template I want to render is just a string, like `"{{ lookup('some_lookup', some_var) }}"`?